# Snowflake SQLAlchemy connection pooling is rolling back transaction by default, while the documentation says the default is commit transaction

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am doing a poc where I wanted to implement connection pooling in python. I took help of snowflake-sqlalchemy as my target is snowflake database. I wanted to check the following scenarios.

1. parallely run multiple stored procedures/sql statements.
2. If the number of SP/SQL which need to execute in parallel is more then the Pool connections, the code should wait. I am writing a while loop for this purpose.
3. I have defined a function func1 and it is executing in parallel multiple times to simulate multiple thread processing.

Problem Description:

Everything is working fine. The pool size is 2 and max_overflow is 5. When the code is running, it is running 7 parallel SP's/SQL's instead of 10. This is understood that the pool only can support 7 connections to run in parallel. If the rest has to execute, they will wait till one of the thread execution is complete. On the snowflake side, the session is established, and the query executes and then rollback is being triggered. I am unable to figure out why roll back is triggered. I tried to explicitly issue a commit statement also from my code. It executes commit and then roll back also is triggered. The second problem is, even if I am not closing the connection, after the thread execution is complete, the connection is being closed automatically and the next set of statements are triggered. Ideally, I was expecting that the thread is not going to release the connection since there is no closure of connection.

Summary: I wanted to know two things.

1. Why is the roll back happening.
2. Why is the connection getting released after thread execution is complete even if the connection is not returned to pool.

May I please request for help in understanding the execution process. I am stuck and unable to figure out what's happening.

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait
from functools import partial
from sqlalchemy.pool import QueuePool
from snowflake.connector import connect


def get_conn():
    return connect(
        user='<username>',
        password="<password>",
        account='<account>',
        warehouse='<WH>',
        database='<DB>',
        schema='<Schema>',
        role='<role>'
    )

pool = QueuePool(get_conn, max_overflow=5, pool_size=2, timeout=10.0)


def func1():
    conn = pool.connect()
    print("Connection is created and SP is triggered")
    print("Pool size is:", pool.size())
    print("Checked OUt connections are:", pool.checkedout())
    print("Checked in Connections are:", pool.checkedin())
    print("Overflow connections are:", pool.overflow())
    print("current status of pool is:", pool.status())
    c = conn.cursor()
    # c.execute("select current_session()")
    c.execute("call SYSTEM$WAIT(60)")
    # c.execute("commit")
    # conn.close()


func_list = []
for _ in range(0, 10):
    func_list.append(partial(func1))

print(func_list)

proc = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for func in func_list:
        print("Calling func")

        while (pool.checkedout() == pool.size() + pool._max_overflow):
            print("Max connections reached. Waiting for an existing connection to release")
            time.sleep(15)

        p = executor.submit(func)
        proc.append(p)
wait(proc)

pool.dispose()
print("process complete")
```

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy are you using? I remember that in 1.4 I was getting always ROLLBACK on the engine due to the fact that [**pool_reset_on_return='rollback'**](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html) and I had to set it to None.

Comment: Thanks Sergiu. I have added this extra argument while creating the pool. I am using version 1.4. I am not creating an engine. I am only using pool. when creating engine Pool_reset_on_return=None will work. If we are creating pool and not engine, then reset_on_return=None will work. Appreciate your response.

Comment: currently my application errors out if the connection pool is exhausted. I have applied a while loop to put all the request on hold till the existing processes release the connection. Is there a way to queue the requests without writing the loop?

Comment: @shankar did you find a solution?

Comment: @yogi: Nope. I haven't found a solution yet.